# On click Icon Open Calendar

Tags: angular, calendar, primeng

Hello guys I'm using the component p-calendar of primeNg and I want to know if is possible to remove the input that appear to open the calendar and instead of this input add only an Icon. I mean, when I click above the Icon the calendar should appear but not when I put the mouse inside the input because I don't want the input that primeNg add by default.

I don't know if this is possible. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is inputStyle and icon properties where u can set width and as ur styles.

```
     <p-calendar [inputStyle]="{'width':'0px', 'border':'0'}" 
[showIcon]="true" icon="fa fa-user"></p-calendar>
```

see the reference for properties here https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar

Comment: there is primeng calendar properties u can see there.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `[showOnFocus]="false"` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. keep your p-calendar component hidden. Please refer below.

> In HTML file

```
<button pButton type="button" (click)="openCalendar($event)" label="Open Calendar"></button>
       <p-calendar
          #calendar
          [hidden]="true"
          [(ngModel)]="selectedDate"
          [readonlyInput]="true"
          appendTo="body"
        ></p-calendar>
```

In TS file.

```
   import { Calendar } from "primeng/primeng";

   @ViewChild("calendar", { static: false }) private calendar: Calendar;

   openCalendar(event: any) {
     this.calendar.showOverlay();
     event.stopPropagation();
   }
```